# adjective or noun + for + object?

Tags: grammar, meaning, adjectives, nouns, objects

It's *impossible* for **the job** to be finished in time.

It's a good *idea* for **us** to travel in separate cars.

There is a definition in the books :

adjective + for + *object* + infinitive

noun+ for + *object* + infinitive

As far as I know, to find the object in the sentence, some questions are asked to the sentence.
( Whom or What )

What do you mean by '' **object** '' in this sentences?
What questions should be asked in this sentences to find the object
?

Answer (score 1):

> [1] *It's impossible* [*for the job to be finished in time*].
>
> [2] *It's a good idea* [*for us to travel in separate cars*].

The book is wrong. "For" is a subordinator here, not a preposition, so "the job" and "us" are not objects.

In both examples, the bracketed expression is a *to*-infinitival clause functioning in [1] as complement of the adjective "impossible" with "the job" as subject, and in [2] as complement of the noun "idea" with "us" as subject.